# get the checked radio button in each radio group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code tries to get the value of the `value` attribute in the checked radio button in each radio group. but can't get it to work.  Thanks

```js
let doc = {};
    $('.radio-group').each(function () {
      doc.id = $(this).attr('_id');
      $(this).children.each(function () {
        let validName = $($(this):checked).attr('value');
        doc.checkedName = validName;
      }
    })
```

```html
<div class='radio-group' _id='abc'>
  <label class='radio-item'>
    <input class='radio-icon' value='value 1' name='g' type='radio'></input>  
    <span class='radio-label'>choose me </span>
  </label>
<label class='radio-item'>
    <input class='radio-icon' value='value 2' name='g' type='radio'></input>  
    <span class='radio-label'>choose me </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.radio-group input:checked').each(function() {$(this).attr('name');});`

Comment: Apologies for comment answer, just bit busy at the mo.. :)

Comment: Why don't you use `id` instead of `_id`?

Comment: Where is attribute "name", and your "value" attribute is inside the "class" attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$(".radio-group input:checked")` you can select every checked input that is child of `.radio-group`.

```js
$(".radio-group input").click(function(){
    var doc = [];
    $(".radio-group input:checked").each(function(index) {
        var id = $(this).closest(".radio-group").attr('_id');
        doc.push(id);
    });
    console.log(doc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-group" _id="id1">
    <input type="radio" /> 
    <label>Item 1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-group" _id="id2">
    <input type="radio" /> 
    <label>Item 2</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-group" _id="id3">
    <input type="radio" /> 
    <label>Item 3</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-group" _id="id4">
    <input type="radio" /> 
    <label>Item 4</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to get each radio group `_id` attribute value as well as the value of the `value` property for the radio button which is selected for said radio group, that is why the loop over all groups. your code will not do that but rather will wait for a click, if that is changed to `each` it will populate the doc with as many radio buttons as there is which is not needed.